# How to use the original sender date instead of the fetch date in OTRS

Tags: otrs, email

When OTRS fetches emails from an IMAP account it forgets the original send date and replaces this with the fetch (!) date.
Normally this is not a problem, but when you're importing an existing IMAP folder with many emails into `OTRS` all dates are set to the import data.

This is not cool and I would like to know if there's some way I can have OTRS read the email headers and use that to replace the `create_time` field in the `article` table.
I was thinking of using the filter module of the postmaster (or something similar).

How do I get OTRS to read the `date` header in the email and use **that** date for the `create_time`?

Comment: You could patch Article.pm if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to add a trigger to MySQL like so:

On `article_attachement`

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_article_attachement_each BEFORE INSERT ON article_attachment
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  DECLARE newdate datetime;
  SET newdate = null;

  SELECT create_time INTO newdate FROM article_plain ap WHERE ap.article_id = new.article_id LIMIT 1;

  IF newdate IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET new.create_time = newdate;
    SET new.change_time = newdate;
  END IF;


END
```

On `article_plain`

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_article_plain_each BEFORE INSERT ON article_plain
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE datestr CHAR(40);
  DECLARE newdate DATETIME;
  DECLARE mindate DATETIME;
  DECLARE myticket BIGINT;

  SET datestr = mid(new.body,locate('Date: ',new.body)+6,40);
  SET newdate = coalesce(str_to_date(datestr,'%a, %e %M %Y %k:%i:%s'),str_to_date(datestr,'%e %M %Y %k:%i:%s'),new.create_time);  

  SET new.create_time = newdate;

  UPDATE article a SET a.create_time = newdate WHERE a.id = new.article_id; 

  SELECT a.ticket_id INTO myticket FROM article a WHERE a.id = new.article_id LIMIT 1;
  SELECT least(min(a.create_time),new.create_time) INTO mindate FROM article a WHERE a.ticket_id = myticket;

  UPDATE ticket t
    SET t.create_time = least(t.create_time, mindate)
        , t.create_time_unix = unix_timestamp(least(t.create_time, mindate))
    WHERE t.id = myticket;

END
```

Same table, but after update

```
CREATE TRIGGER ua_article_plain_each AFTER UPDATE ON article_plain
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF old.create_time <> new.create_time THEN BEGIN

    UPDATE article a SET a.create_time = new.create_time, a.change_time = new.create_time WHERE a.id = new.article_id;

  END; END IF;

END
```

Finally a trigger on `ticket`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bu_ticket_each BEFORE UPDATE ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE newtn varchar(50);
  DECLARE newdate varchar(12);
  DECLARE filter varchar(13);
  SET newdate = date_format(old.create_time,'%Y%m%d%H%i');
  SET filter = concat(newdate,'%');
  SELECT concat(newdate,ifnull(right(concat('0000',right(max(tn),4)+1),4),'0001')) INTO newtn 
    FROM ticket
    WHERE tn LIKE filter;
  SET new.tn = newtn;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: this is not possible. The long answer is: if you want to do this you need to modify the TicketCreate() method, because it will currently only take the current time as create date for a new ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem.
Thank you very much for this Help.
The Procedures didn´t work for me, so i changed it and work with a temporary-Table.

```
CREATE TABLE `article_plain_date` (
  `article_plain_FK` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `atricle_ID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket_ID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_plain_FK`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO article_plain_date
SELECT p.id,a.id,t.id,IF(STR_TO_DATE(MID(body,LOCATE('Date: ',body)+6,25),'%a, %e %M %Y %k:%i:%s'),STR_TO_DATE(MID(body,LOCATE('Date: ',body)+6,25),'%a, %e %M %Y %k:%i:%s'),p.create_time) AS create_date  FROM otrs.article_plain p

JOIN article a ON (p.`article_id` = a.id)
JOIN ticket t ON (a.`ticket_id` = t.id);

UPDATE article_plain p
JOIN article_plain_date d ON (p.`article_id` = d.`atricle_ID`)
SET p.`create_time` = d.`create_date`;

UPDATE article a
JOIN article_plain_date d ON (a.id = d.`atricle_ID`)
SET a.`create_time` = d.`create_date`;

UPDATE ticket t
JOIN article_plain_date d ON (t.id = d.`ticket_ID`)
SET t.`create_time` = d.`create_date`, t.`create_time_unix` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d.`create_date`);
```